# Difference between domain and co-domain in sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let's say I have a subset of the Cartesian plane, for example:

$\{(x, y) \in R \times R: 2x+3 > 5\}$.

If I am asked to find the co-domain of the following set, how would I do so? I know how to find the domain, which is done by finding all possible $(x,y)$ ordered pairs and then placing all the $x$ values in a set. But how is this different from the co-domain?

Thank you very much!

Comment: the co-domain is all the $y$ values.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen My mistake, you're right. How would it be different from the range though?

Comment: Definitions here aren’t completely standard. What are your course’s definitions?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen my textbook, How to Prove It, defines the range as the set of all $b$ that are elements of some set $B$ such that there exists an $a$ that is an element of $A$ such that $(a, b)$ is an element of the relation $R$. However, my textbook does not mention co-domain.

Comment: Sets do not have domains or codomain.  Functions do.

Comment: @WilliamElliot my question asks about a relation between two sets though.

Comment: Sometimes 'co-domain' refers to some set that we know the function or relation's image (what you're calling the range) falls in. This is usually in the context of a function. For instance, we might say "let $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$" be a function and call $\mathbb R$ the codomain. We don't guarantee every element in $\mathbb R$ will have a preimage in $\mathbb N$ (in fact that's impossible in this case). The image generally refers to the subset of $\mathbb R$ of elements that actually has a preimage in $\mathbb N.$ "Range" is sometimes used to mean codomain, and sometimes used to mean image.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see, so co-domain is kind of like the boundaries within which the range will fall? So would it be acceptable to say that the co-domain for the given subset of the Cartesian plane is all real numbers?

Comment: @DeepLearner Sure. (But then again that's the range/image here too.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see the difference now. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: @DeepLearner If you are satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, a set of ordered pairs in and of itself has neither a domain nor a codomain; domains and codomains are defined on functions.

If we assume the set of ordered pairs given by $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} : 2x+3>5 \}$ are all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ of some function $f:A \to B$ such that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, then the domain $A$ consists of all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $2x+3>5$, or in other words, $x>1$. And the codomain $B$ consists of all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ since there is no condition on $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, domain and co-domain are defined on functions, but we'll use your textbook's definition for domain and co-domain on relations.

In your relation, note that your set describes only the $x$-values, $2x+3>5$, i.e. $x>1$. So the $x$-values that satisfy this condition is your domain, as defined in your textbook. However, since there is no condition on your $y$-values, all of $\mathbb{R}$ is your co-domain.

Comment: Please explain why you downvoted my answer and what you think I can do to improve it. It's a little confusing because our answers were similar before and identical now that you've updated yours to reflect mine.

Comment: I'm still waiting on an answer. Be warned that petty and/or vindictive downvoting is not acceptable on SE and will be reported to the mods unless you can provide an explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't downvote you. However, I edited mine to improve my answer since someone downvoted mine. The only changes I made were to include a note on domains on relations and simplifying the inequality. Our answers are similar for the fact that the answer is pretty simple. I can delete my answer if you want and have yours be the only one.